# Proxy Pass with Cookie Value in URL

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I want to proxy pass a request to `/foo/XXX/bar` where `XXX` is the value of the `mycookie` cookie in the request.

This is trivial in Nginx but I have found no way in Apache HTTPD:

### Nginx Solution

```
location ~ ^/foo/bar {
    proxy_pass http://localhost/foo/$cookie_cust/bar$is_args$args;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}
```

How can I `ProxyPass` with a specific cookie value in Apache 2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than Apache's `proxy_pass`  directive use a mod_rewrite rule. The mod_rewrite [`[P | proxy]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) target provides similar functionality as Apache's proxy_pass directive.

I.e. something along the lines of: (un-tested and probably not immediately suitable for your purposes)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookiename=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule "/foo/bar/(.*)$" "http://localhost/foo/%1/bar/$1" [P]
```

where the RewriteCond matches the value of a cookie with the name of "cookiename" and the `%1`  in the target URL is RewriteCond backreference to that value

Comment: Thanks! Could you adapt the answer to show how to extract 2 cookies (foo and bar) into `%1` and `%2`?

Comment: Gottit `[\s\S]*foo=(\w+);[\s\S]*bar=(\w+)[; ]?` - obviously if the cookie order changes we're screwed.